# Blocking lua script redis or not?

Tags: redis

I use simple lua script for redis 4 :

```
        local result = {}
        local vcounters = redis.call( "zrange", "vcounters::"..date, 0, -1, "withscores" )
        local i = 1
        while i < #vcounters do
            local vid = vcounters[i]
            if result[vid] == nil  then result[vid] = 0 end
            result[vid] = result[vid] + 
            (redis.call("scard", "vcounters::"..date.."::session::"..vid) or 0)
            i = i + 2
        end
        return cjson.encode(result)
```

it is alternative zrange/scard command from client script and works 4-5 times faster. But will this script block the zadd commands or not ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, while the script is running, no other database commands will be executed (they have to [wait until it is done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261631/why-lua-script-block-redis-server?rq=1)).

On the plus side, if you need this to be atomic, the script won't be interleaved with concurrent database updates either (whereas issuing individual commands from the client might be mixed with commands from other clients).

Comment: As a side note - never encode or generate key names in the script. Always pass them as input via the built-in `KEYS[]` Lua table.